# AttributeError: stat instance has no attribute X?

Tags: python, class, object

When running the following code, I get `AttributeError: stat instance has no attribute 'printStats'`. What is the problem here?

```
class stat():
    def __init__(self, fname, blocks, backEdges):
        self.fname = fname
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.backEdges = backEdges

    def printStats(self):
        print self.fname + str(self.blocks) + str(self.backEdges)

element = stat("a", 1, 2)
element.printStats()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indentation is goofed, mixing tabs and spaces. Use `python -tt` to verify.

Comment: I am using tab but python -tt tells me that printStats is not tabbed. How come?

Comment: ... Are you asking me why your editor did things differently?

Comment: @user1018562 Are you using the Tab key or is your editor configured to use tabs? There's a difference